# Displaying sub content (entity references) of node based only with specific taxonomy

Tags: 8, views, nodes

I have been working on a solution that would allow training courses to be created using Drupal 8 as the backbone. I have elected not to use the "Courses" module and am simply using custom content types.

At this point I have the following:

Course Content Type -> which contains entity references (1 or more) to Slide Content Types -> which contain Entity references (1 or more) -> to Text or Media content (these are also custom content types). I chose not to use Paragraphs for a few reasons.

Right now I just have "Text" and "Media" content types, but plan on creating additional content types that can be added to a slide -> which in turn is added to the course.

The Text/Media both include a "Taxonomy" term that can be selected.

My goal is to be able to view a course and filter the content (the text/media) based on whether they contain a specific Taxonomy term.

I am considering how to do this using custom views, but cant figure out how to reference the Taxonomy term of the entity referenced content rather than the course object itself.

The end goal would be to have a single course object that may have some content with the Taxonomy term: student and other content with the taxonomy term instructor (some may have both taxonomies selected). I would then be able to view the same course and see some content if I view it as the instructor and different content if it is viewed as a student.

Comment: did you try relationships in views?

Comment: @Arun, yes I started looking at those, but may need to dig a bit deeper and look at doing it a different way. If I have a Course content type which references the Slide content type which finally references the Text/Media content types (and this is where my taxonomy is). I found a few tutorials that show me how to create a view for a content type and show all of those references, but that is not quite what I want to do. I need to go a little farther.